# Python convert a long string to a list without single quotes

Tags: python, string, list, quotes

I have a long string that I want store it as a list. But it always has single quotes at the beginning and the end. How to remove them? Thanks.

Samples

```
>>> string
>>> '"2012-11-05", "filename", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0.11, 0.22, 0.33'
>>> string.split("'")
>>> ['"2012-11-05", "filename", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0.11, 0.22, 0.33']
```

Question is how can I get result like this below without single quotes?

```
>>> ["2012-11-05", "filename", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0.11, 0.22, 0.33]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your data seems to be a valid python tuple.

```
import ast

list(ast.literal_eval('"2012-11-05", "filename", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0.11, 0.22, 0.33'))
```

The literal_eval function from the ast module is safer than plain eval, because literal_eval will not evaluate arbitrary code, just plain values.

Comment: Awesome, I am so glad I know this module exists now, thankyou.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
[s.replace('"', '').strip() for s in string.split(',')]

>>> ['2012-11-05', 'filename', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '0.11', '0.22', '0.33']
```

Comment: This doesn't match the output given. It looks like he wants the numbers to be stored as ints/floats, not strings.

Comment: Yep, I want to keep strings stored as string, numbers as ints/floats.

Answer (score -1):

```
      python 3.2

      string='"2012-11-05", "filename", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0.11, 0.22, 0.33'
      a=eval(string)
      res=list(a)
```

Comment: -1: eval() is dangerous for untrusted data, as it can execute arbitrary Python code.